# metabox select - frontend display

Tags: metabox, front-end, dropdown

Hi I bought a theme but I need to add some fields to a frontend submission form.
I added the metaboxes and they are working but the problem is the select type of metaboxes.

I cloned a select form group that gets the data from the post taxonomies but I don't know how to tweak it to make it "grab" the data from the 'items' array.

Here's my metabox:

```
array(
    'type'  => 'select',
    'name'  => 'resume_change_location',
    'label' => __( 'Are you willing to change location?', 'jobboard' ),
    'description'   => __( '' ),
    'items' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 'yes',
            'label' => __( 'Yes', 'jobboard' ),
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 'no',
            'label' => __( 'No', 'jobboard' ),
        ),
    ),

),
```

Here's the dropdown for the taxonomy data (working):

```
<select name="job_type" id="job_type" class="form-control">
                            <option value=""><?php echo '-- '.__( 'Select Type', 'jobboard' ).' --'; ?></option>
                        <?php
                            $terms = get_terms( 'job_type', array( 'hide_empty' => false, ) );
                            foreach( $terms as $term ){
                                $selected = '';
                                if( $default['job_type'] == $term->slug ){
                                    $selected = 'selected';
                                }
                                echo '<option value="'.$term->slug.'" '.$selected.'>'.esc_attr($term->name).'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                        </select>
```

I would like to show the dropdown with the items in my metabox...here's what I got but it is not showing my items (it is showing the dropdown but with blank options)

```
<select class="form-control" name="change">
                        <option value=""><?php _e( 'Select', 'jobboard' ); ?></option>
                    <?php
                        $change = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, 'resume_change_location', true);
                        foreach( $change as $key){
                            $selected = '';
                            if( $key->name == $default['resume_change_location'] ){
                                $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                            }//endif;
                            echo '<option value="'.$key->name.'" '.$selected.'>'.esc_attr($key->name).'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
```

I have been looking for a way to make this work for about 3 hours with no luck... Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$change = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, 'resume_change_location', true);
```

From https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

get_post_meta returns an array, not an object so you need to use 
    $change['index']

The other thing is within your meta box you seem to be saving a string not an array so foreach is going to fail.

The below should work...

```
    $change = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, 'resume_change_location', true );
    <option value=""><?php _e( 'Select', 'jobboard' ); ?></option>
    <option value="Yes"<?php selected( 'Yes', $default['resume_change_location'] ); ?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="No"<?php selected( 'No', $default['resume_change_location'] ); ?>>No</option>
    </select>
```

Also notice my use of the built-in WordPress selected function - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected

Comment: Thanks the values are now showing. I think I forgot to say that I need the front end and backend to be working (can edit via frontend or backend). I think this is working frontend, but how can I "bond" the options to the backend too? Thanks!!